# How to define (*>), (<*) in terms of (<*>) and pure?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative

I can define them using monads.

```
(<*) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m a
(<*) fa fb = fa >>= \a -> (fb >>= \_ -> return a)
(<*) fa fb = ??? -- In terms of pure & (<*>)

(*>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
(*>) fa fb = fa >>= \_ -> (fb >>= \b -> return b)
(*>) fa fb = ??? -- In terms of pure & (<*>)
```

`(\*>)` and `(<\*)` are considered as sequencing operators. Can I safely assume that Applicatives can do work in both Sequential and Parallel? Monads are just a  sub category of applicatives only capable of doing things sequentiallay. And  even though it doesn't matter the order of operations for few monads like the reader monad (example reading configurations from a `HashMap` of environment settings)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard definition is

```
(<*) :: Applicative m => m a -> m b -> m a
(<*) fa fb = (\a _ -> a) <$> fa <*> fb
```

We can then apply the law `f <$> x = pure f <*> x` to only use `<*>` and `pure`.

The other one is analogous.

Comment: Thanks got it. (<*) fa fb = liftA2 (\a _ -> a) fa fb  && (*>) fa fb = liftA2 (\_ b -> b) fa fb. Can also please comment on my assumptions to the bottom of the question.

Comment: @PKChem I don't understand the last part of your question. Are you referring to two other type classes `Sequential` and `Parallel`? I don't know about those, sorry.